# What does "chi" mean in football fan language?

Tags: football, fans

In an English football match, a player left the pitch, giving the impression that he had been injured by another player, then went along the goal line and returned to the pitch without an injury. A fan shouted something which sounded like "chi-chi-chi".

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that the fan was actually chanting "Cheat! Cheat!", and their English accent made it sound like "chi, chi" (as an Englishman myself, I can affirm that we tend not to pronounce our "T"s, especially in informal settings like football matches). In this case, the "cheating" would be the footballer pretending to be injured in order to win a free kick and/or get play to be stopped. This is indeed cheating (specifically, [simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_(association_football))), and is strongly frowned upon by most football fans.